# How do I write a function that converts character vector to date vector in R?

Tags: r

This seems like a simple enough function to write, but I think I'm misunderstanding the requirements for formal arguments / how R parses and evaluates a function.

I'm trying to write a function that converts any character vector of the form `"%m/%d/%Y"` (and belonging to data.frame `df`) to a date vector, and formats it as `"%m/%d/%Y"`, as follows:

```
dateformat <- function(x) {
  df$x <- (format(as.Date(df$x, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y"))
}
```

I was thinking that...

```
dateformat(a)
```

... would just take the `"a"` as the actual argument for `x` and plug it into the function, thus resolving as:

```
 df$a <- (format(as.Date(df$a, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

However, I get the following error when running `dateformat(a)`:

```
Error in as.Date.default(df$x, format = "%m/%d/%Y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'df$x' to class “Date”
```

Can someone please explain why my understanding of formal/actual arguments and/or R function parsing/evaluation is incorrect? Thank you.

**Update**

Of course, for all the variables I want to convert to dates (e.g., `df$a`, `df$b`, `df$c`), I could just write

`df$a <- (format(as.Date(df$a, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y"))`

`df$b <- (format(as.Date(df$b, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y"))`

`df$c <- (format(as.Date(df$c, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y"))`

But I'm looking to improve my coding skills by making a more general function to which I could feed a vector of variables. For instance, what if I had `df$a` to `df$z`, all character variables that I wanted to convert to date variables? After I write a proper function, I'd like to then perhaps run it  like so:

```
for (n in letters) {
  dateformat(n)
}
```

Comment: just remove the `df$x <- ` from the formula and it should work. also how are you using the function?

Comment: @rawr I still get the same error after removing `df$x <-`. See my edits for justification and how I'm using the function.

Comment: in the function, x is a generic input so you don't need df$x, just x: `dateformat <- function(x) format(as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `format(...)` function returns a character vector, not a date, so if `x` is a string,

```
format(as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

converts `x` to date and then back to character, as in:

```
result <- format(as.Date("01/03/2014", format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y")
result
# [1] "01/03/2014"
class(result)
# [1] "character"
```

Second, referencing an object, such as `df`, in a function, on the LHS of an expression, causes R to create that object in the scope of the function.

```
a <- 2
f <- function(x) a <- x
f(3)
a
# [1] 2
```

Here, we set a variable, `a`, to `2`. Then in the function we create a new variable, `a` in the scope of the function, set it to `x` (3), and destroy it when the function returns. So in the global environment `a` is still `2`.

If you insist on using a `dateformat(...)` function, this should work work:

```
df <- data.frame(a=paste("01",1:10,"2014",sep="/"),
                 b=paste("02",11:20,"2014",sep="/"),
                 c=paste("03",21:30,"2014",sep="/"))

dateformat <- function(x) as.Date(df[[x]], format = "%m/%d/%Y")
for (n in letters[1:3]) df[[n]] <- dateformat(n)
sapply(df,class)
#      a      b      c 
# "Date" "Date" "Date"
```

This will be more efficient though:

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df,as.Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Comment: Wonderful response, @jlhoward. I'm not familiar with `do.call()`, but after Googling it and comparing `lapply(df, as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")`, `data.frame(lapply(df, as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))`, and `do.call(data.frame,lapply(df,as.Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"))`, it appears that the second and third options do the same thing. Why the `do.call` then?

Comment: Yeah, I overuse `do.call(...)`. The best way is with `as.data.frame(...)`. I edited the answer.